# Error wont dissapear, even when deleting/commenting the faulty lines

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, typeerror

im am using Linux Ubuntu on a Virtual machine on Windows 10.

I have downloaded a IPython Notebook from [dms_tools](https://github.com/jbloomlab/dms_tools2/blob/master/examples/Dingens2018/analysis_notebook.ipynb)

Now when I try to run certain parts of the code I become the following error:

```
/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/version.py in _cmp(self, other)
    335         if self.version == other.version:
    336             return 0
--> 337         if self.version < other.version:
    338             return -1
    339         if self.version > other.version:

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Since I did not know, hot to solve this problem I decided to just eddit this version.py file (perhaps not so smart, but I did not know what else to do...)

I just decided to Comment the faulty lines and return 0 everytime.

Now the weird part, I still get the same error pointing on the comments:

```
 /usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/version.py in _cmp(self, other)
        335         # if self.version == other.version:
        336         #     return 0
    --> 337         # if self.version < other.version:
        338         #     return -1
        339         # if self.version > other.version:

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Now I tested what would happen if I just added some empty new lines and the error looks like this
(pointing at the same line, where nothing even is):

```
  /usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/version.py in _cmp(self, other)
        335         
        336           
    --> 337         
        338             
        339         

    TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

I just can not explain what is happening here and I hope someone has an idea.

The complete Traceback is:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_2888/2193680867.py in <module>
      1 fastqdir = os.path.join(resultsdir, './FASTQ_files/')
      2 print("Downloading FASTQ files from the SRA...")
----> 3 dms_tools2.sra.fastqFromSRA(
      4         samples=samples,
      5         fastq_dump='/home/andreas/sratoolkit.2.11.0-ubuntu64/bin/fastq-dump',

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dms_tools2/sra.py in fastqFromSRA(samples, fastq_dump, fastqdir, aspera, overwrite, passonly, no_downloads, ncpus)
     91                               .decode('utf-8').split(':')[-1].strip())
     92     fastq_dump_minversion = '2.8'
---> 93     if not (distutils.version.LooseVersion(fastq_dump_version) >=
     94             distutils.version.LooseVersion(fastq_dump_minversion)):
     95         raise RuntimeError("fastq-dump version {0} is installed. You need "

/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/version.py in __ge__(self, other)
     68 
     69     def __ge__(self, other):
---> 70         c = self._cmp(other)
     71         if c is NotImplemented:
     72             return c

/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/version.py in _cmp(self, other)
    335         if self.version == other.version:
    336             return 0
--> 337         if self.version < other.version:
    338             return -1
    339         if self.version > other.version:

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: Which lines of code produce this error? Also: yes, it sounds like a bad idea to edit python built in modules

Comment: Line 20 of the second cod-block: ----> 3 dms_tools2.sra.fastqFromSRA(

Comment: Check the version of python you are running vs what the module should be run against. This is a typical error if using `input()` on python_2 vs `input()` on python_3. With python_2 it would have provided `int` if you give it f.e. `42` as input. With python 3 you get strings from it.

Comment: Can you add the complete traceback to your question?

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but where can I see in VS-code the Python-version it is using? I thought I was using 3.8

Comment: your errors show `/usr/lib/python3.8`  - VS shows the used python in the lower left hand of the IDE Screen - `import sys     print(sys.version)` will print the runtime python version

Comment: What's your fastq-dump and dms_tools version?

Comment: I added the whole traceback

Comment: I use the fastq-dump comming with "SRA Toolkit 2.11.0". The dms_tools2 version is 2.6.10. DMS_Tools_2 states it should be run with "Python 3.6 or higher"

Comment: Thx for the info, that is the issue

Comment: What exactly? I cannot quite follow you :)

Comment: Sorry for that, should have been more clear. Your info helped to identify the issue which led to my answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your fastq-dump version. Looking at the source code that generates the error from `sra.py`:

```
fastq_dump_version = (subprocess.check_output([fastq_dump, '--version'])
                          .decode('utf-8')
                          .replace('"fastq-dump" version', '').split(':'))
    if len(fastq_dump_version) == 1:
        fastq_dump_version = fastq_dump_version[0].strip()
    elif len(fastq_dump_version) == 2:
        fastq_dump_version = fastq_dump_version[1].strip()
    else:
        fastq_dump_version = (subprocess.check_output([fastq_dump, '--help'])
                              .decode('utf-8').split(':')[-1].strip())
    fastq_dump_minversion = '2.8'
    if not (distutils.version.LooseVersion(fastq_dump_version) >=
            distutils.version.LooseVersion(fastq_dump_minversion)):
        raise RuntimeError("fastq-dump version {0} is installed. You need "
            "at least version {1}".format(fastq_dump_version, 
            fastq_dump_minversion))
```

There is an assumption about the output of `fastq-dump --version`, i.e. that there is a `:` right before the version being output. This is not the case for 2.11 though and the subprocess call results in this:

```
>>> (subprocess.check_output(['sratoolkit.2.11.0-ubuntu64/bin/fastq-dump', '--version']).decode('utf-8').replace('"fastq-dump" version', '').split(':'))
['\n"sratoolkit.2.11.0-ubuntu64/bin/fastq-dump" version 2.11.0\n\n']
```

this string is then used for the version comparison further down and `distutils` complains about being unable to compare it to the version `2.8` saved in `fastq_dump_minversion`.

The easiest way to fix this is to use another version of the sra toolkit. Version 2.9 should work, as the version output seems to match the expectation:

```
>>> (subprocess.check_output(['sratoolkit.2.9.0-ubuntu64/bin/fastq-dump', '--version']).decode('utf-8').replace('"fastq-dump" version', '').split(':'))
['\nsratoolkit.2.9.0-ubuntu64/bin/fastq-dump ', ' 2.9.0\n\n']
```

**Additional Info**

Why did changing `lib/python3.7/distutils/version.py` not do the trick? There is a precompiled file in `lib/python3.7/distutils/__pycache__` that is being read instead or the actual `lib/python3.7/distutils/version.py`. If you edit `version.py`, you should delete the coresponding file in the `__pycache__` dir. Note though, that I strongly recommend to **not mess with these files**, as you can easily break your python if you don't know what you are doing.

**P.S.**

This should be fixed in `dms_tools` version 2.6.11

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try it with another version of the sra_toolkit.

Comment: Let me know if that fixes your problem

Comment: Yes, I have tried it and the Files are getting downloaded :) Thank you once again!

Answer (score -1):

First of all, the error `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'` means that one of the operands you are using in condition checking is string data type and another is integer data type.

You can check what's what by using type() function.

Next what you can do is rename the file using mv command and run again using:

```
python <filename.py>
```

Answer (score -2):

In short: you are trying to compare two different data types.
If you're sure that both values are number, you can convert the value before compare:

```
if int(self.version) < int(other.version):
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! The weird thing, this is happening in a python-script and it wont change when I change this script. Also I cannot explayn why this error appears exactly.